# Will scarring effect my horse's placement in a showing class?

Tags: horses, uk, competitions

My horse is now almost 3. (a week away) This year we were supposed to start showing in-hand (UK)

However, when she was first introduced to our lower herd in November/December she unfortunately caught the wrong end of our chestnut Arabian who scored quite the mark on her kneecap.

As far as I'm aware, if you enter any competition that includes UNICEF standards you are not allowed to apply makeup to the scars as it goes against their rules.

Other than cosmetic reasons the scar does not affect her movement in any way shape or form and she moves beautifully which is the only reason I'm considering showing her when this lockdown is over.

In which case I would like to know:

- Will the scar affect the judges choice?
- Are there any home remedies to soften or smooth scaring?

[image]

Comment: This biting gelding that she's sharing with is not going to help.

Comment: Maybe not but as she’s rugged the bites don’t land on her. This particular scar was done by a kick from the other mare in the paddock. I’m always amazed by how well scars heal up

Comment: It _should not_ affect the placement, but in reality, horse sport is highly irrational and so are the placements. It absolutely depends on the judge's impression which can be made up off anything.